# How to add total sample size of each facet to geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add total sample size of each facet to `geom_histogram`.Expect output as below:
[image]
After read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289861/7936836) ,I write script as below:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(.,mapping=aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth= 0.1)+
  stat_summary(fun = median, fun.max = length,
               geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(max)), vjust = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

But get error:`Error: stat_summary requires the following missing aesthetics: y`.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can be added inside facets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
iris %>% left_join(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()))%>%
  mutate(Label=paste0(Species,' (Sample size = ',N,')')) %>%
  ggplot(.,mapping=aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth= 0.1)+
  facet_wrap(~Label)
```

It will add a label with sample size to facets:

[image]

**Update**

You can also try:

```
iris %>% add_count(.,Species) %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(n=ifelse(row_number(n)!=1,NA,n)) %>%
  ggplot(.,mapping=aes(x=Sepal.Length))+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth= 0.1)+ 
  facet_wrap(~Species)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=n,y=8),size=5,vjust=-0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: @kittygirl You can but you will have to define the position!

Comment: `iris %>% add_count(.,Species) %>% 
  ggplot(.,mapping=aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth= 0.1)+
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  geom_text(aes(label=n,y=8),size=2)` is fine,but `n` repeated each histogram,how to let it show only once?

Comment: @kittygirl Ready! I have updated the solution as you wanted :)