# no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('fseq', 'function')" when use R pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919793/how-to-add-total-sample-size-of-each-facet-to-geom-histogram),
`iris %>% left_join(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()))` is part of answer.

I translate this script to:
`iris %>% {left_join(.,. %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()))}`,but got error:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('fseq', 'function')"
```

I think 2 script are equal,what cause the error?

Comment: If it is to create a new column, you can do `iris %>% add_count(Species)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this Kitty:

```
iris %>% left_join(x = ., y = {.} %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this more directly in creating a column with `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
      add_count(Species)
```

---

If we are using the `%>%`, it is recommended not to make it overly cumbersome with inserting `{}` inside the  flow, instead it can be

```
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>%  # grouping done
     summarise(N = n()) %>%  # get summarised count
     right_join(iris, .)  # right or left join
```

This chain makes it easier to understand.  As others have noted, there is a way to do this by wrapping it containerized in `{}`, however, IMHO that would also defeat the whole purpose of chaining.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) as it seems like it evaluates the `.%>% ...` sequence to something else:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
    left_join({
        print(. %>%
                  mutate(new = 5L))
    },
    copy = TRUE)
#> Functional sequence with the following components:
#> 
#>  1. mutate(., new = 5L)
#> 
#> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(y): cannot coerce class 'c("fseq", "function")' to a data.frame
```

You may want to report the issue to Github or I can follow-up with it on Github - not sure if this is more [magrittr](/questions/tagged/magrittr) or [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). I used to use similar pipes. As @duck notes, it appears wrapping `{.}` around the dot escapes whatever is happening.

```r
iris %>%
    {
        {.}%>%
            group_by(Species)%>%
            summarize(N = n())
    }
```

Also... the inevitable `data.table` alternative:

```r
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(iris)
dt[, N := .N, by = Species]
dt
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species  N
#>   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 50
#>   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 50
#>   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 50
#>   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 50
#>   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 50
#>  ---                                                               
#> 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 50
#> 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 50
#> 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 50
#> 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 50
#> 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 50
```

Comment: Thanks.I am not familiar with github,pls let Hadley know this.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5414

Comment: The issue is now closed. I guess this is by design to create functions with the pipe.

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5414